# What is the issue with this function, that shows the most recent post made by a specific user?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, variables

I created a function, and would like to know why it isn't working. This is the code:

```
function new_post() {
    $session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'first_name', 'email', 'avatar', 'rank', 'petnumber');
    $username = $user_data['username'];
    $sqlpost = "SELECT id FROM forum_question WHERE name=$username ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1";
    $mysqlpost = mysql_query($sqlpost);
    return $mysqlpost;
}
```

Also, I am in the process of updating my entire website to PDO/mysqli, I just want to get this working in regular mysql before I go on to updating it.

This is how I am using it:

```
<a href="view_topic.php?id=<?php echo new_post(); ?>">View New Post</a>
```

And also, `$session_user_id` and  `$user_data` are both defined in my `init.php` file aswell.

Also, I'm not getting any errors, but this is what's showing up in my URL `http://view_topic.php/?id=Resource%20id%20#14`

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think `new_post()` has access to `$user_data` unless it's passed as an argument to the function.

Comment: Do you know how I could go about doing that?

Comment: `$result = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlpost); return $result['id'];`

Comment: @asbxzeeko I'm not sure if this is the best way but maybe you could set is as a session variable? `$_SESSION['user_data'] = user_data(...)`.  I guess you'll need to do this in your `init.php` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably

```
$sqlpost = "SELECT id FROM forum_question WHERE name='$username' ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1";
```

because SQL requires strings to be quoted

and don't forget to fetch the result from the resultset and extract the column value from the array:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlpost); 
return $result['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sqlpost should be actually:
`$sqlpost = "SELECT id FROM forum_question WHERE name='".$username."' ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1";`